# QR Code size randomly changes when printed - CAB SQUIX 4 M - JScript programming language

Tags: label, qr-code, jscript, cab

I have a weird issue when printing **QR Codes** on **CAB Squix 4M** printer.
Randomly happens that the QR Code size changes (will be bigger then normal).

**Snippet of the label :**

```
B 21.7,2.0,270,QRCODE,0.48;X-HM://0066F33LTBD61
```

*The input is always the same number of characters 20.*

**Examples >**

1. X-HM://0066DW8YA0GX6 > normal size
2. X-HM://0066F33LTBD61 > bigger than normal

Can anyone explain me the logic ?

Comment: There are different ways to generate a QR code from the same message - can you show the two particular codes which you get from these inputs (which are not necessarily the same codes I get now when I test it with another software)?

Comment: I you are willing to see the QR Code on images, I cant help you because there is a restriction on printer which is  handling the issue when the barcode is too big and will not be printed.

Comment: I'd say the first QRcode leaves more room to being compressed by the algorithm than the other. Character count != qrcode size. Also error correction level has influence on that.

Besides that;
 I've recently picked up Jscript and Im struggling to get it to work. I know this is an old post and I know this is now what answers are for but I simply cannot find any other help - That being said do you have any learning material or could summarize how you send the label to the printer (e.g. ftp, USB, what library used).